# pointer to static as template parameter / instantiate a template using a c string

Tags: c++, string, templates, pointers, static

I know this code is evil, i know i shouldn't do this, i know i will burn in coder hell for this but anyway:

As one know it is possible to use `int` as a `template parmerer` like `std::get` goes.
I would like to use a `char *`

```
template<char * str>
struct printer {
    void operator() () const {
        std::cout<<str;
    }
};
```

so far with help of [this article](http://blog.asymptotic.co.uk/2011/02/c-pointer-template-parameters-are-weird/) i managed to get this compiling and running

```
template<char ** str>
struct printer {
    void operator() () const {
        std::cout<< *str;
    }
};

extern char * bla;
char * bla = (char *)"bla content";

int main() {
    printer<&bla> print;
    print();
}
```

which has two disadvantages:

1. double pointers
2. **i have to define the values (strings content) far from where i use them**

perfect would be

```
printer<"bla"> print;
```

but the compiler obviously don't like this

can anyone help me overcome at least the the latter "problem"

*edit*
I am using g++ 4.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to use it as a template argument, here's a new try then! :)

**Edit:**

http://ideone.com/NGgXxT

```
template<char... str>
struct staticString {
    static std::string c_str() {
        return std::string{str...}.c_str();
    }
};
```

Basically, `char...` variadic should do the trick.

Comment: i just get `error: could not convert template argument ` when trying to use this class...

Comment: @Valerij Well, it does compile in IDEone :).

Comment: but not when used as a template parameter as i intend to do

Comment: @Valerij try this if you don't just need a compile time string (but actually really really have the urge to use it as a template parameter)